# What Is the Function of Less Than (<) Operator in numpy Array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning Python right now and I'm stuck with this line of code I found on the internet. I can not understand what actually this line of code do.

Suppose I have this array:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array ([[1,5],[8,1],[10,0.5]]
y = x[np.sqrt(x[:,0]**2+x[:,1]**2) < 1]
print (y)
```

The result is an empty array. What I want to know is what does actually the *y* do? I've never encountered this kind of code before. It seems like the square brackets is like the *if-conditional* statement. Instead of that code, If write this line of code:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array ([[1,5],[8,1],[10,0.5]]
y = x[0 < 1]
print (y)
```

It will return exactly what *x* is (because zero IS less than one). 
Assuming that it is a way to write *if-conditional* statement, I find it really absurd because I'm comparing an array with an integer. 
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I suspect `0 < 1` returns a `bool` which then evaluates as an `int` so you get the first or second element of the array.

Comment: `0 < 1` evaluates to `True`. You are doing `x[True]`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 `x[1] != x[True]`.

Comment: @timgeb In the REPL it is, for `list`s at least.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 but we are not talking about lists.

Comment: I can't find something in the docs about using scalars for boolean indexing, btw. `x[True]` seems to be a shorthand for `x[[True, True, True], :]`.

Comment: @timgeb thanks. in other languages, the same would be true (where it gets cast to an int for array access) so it's definitely something numpy-specific.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 really? IIRC only C/C++ do that implicitly.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Well, I suppose I work with primarily C-based languages and made an incorrect assumption here.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Actually Python itself does that for lists and tuples (`[1, 2, 3][True] == 2`). And (surprisingly) even dicts (`{1: 2}[True] == 2`).

Comment: @jdehesa true, but not for `np.array`s (`np.array([3, 4, 5])[True] == np.array([[3, 4, 5]])`), as pointed out by `timgeb`.

Comment: @jdehesa Python's native bool() is actually a wonky subclass of int() with some special properties, valued 0 and 1 for False/True. Try it yourself: True + True + True == 3, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

In Numpy:

> [1,1,2,3,4] < 2

is (very roughly) equivalent to something like:

> [x<2 for x in [1,1,2,3,4]]

for vanilla Python lists. And as such, in both cases, the result would be:

> [True, True, False, False, False]

The same holds true for some other functions, like addition, multiplication and so on.  Broadcasting is actually a major selling point for Numpy.

Now, another thing you can do in Numpy is boolean indexing, which is providing an array of bools that are interpreted as 'Keep this value Y/N?'. So:

```
arr = [1,1,2,3,4]
res = arr[arr<2]

# evaluates to:
=> [1,1]
```

Comment: This does not fully answer the question. OP is not indexing with an array of bools. They are indexing with `True`.

Comment: Fair enough - OP was basically asking two separate, largely independent, questions and I took it to mean he was mostly confused about comparing arrays with scalars, not the broadcasting behavior of the boolean indexing.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` works differently when you slice an array using a `boolean` or an `int`.

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> This advanced indexing occurs when obj is an array object of Boolean type, such as may be returned from comparison operators. A single
>   boolean index array is practically identical to x[obj.nonzero()]
>   where, as described above, obj.nonzero() returns a tuple (of length
>   obj.ndim) of integer index arrays showing the True elements of obj.
>   However, it is faster when obj.shape == x.shape.
>
> If obj.ndim == x.ndim, x[obj] returns a 1-dimensional array filled
>   with the elements of x corresponding to the True values of obj. The
>   search order will be row-major, C-style. If obj has True values at
>   entries that are outside of the bounds of x, then an index error will
>   be raised. If obj is smaller than x it is identical to filling it with
>   False.

When you index an array using booleans, you are telling `numpy` to select the data corresponding to `True`, therefore `array[True]` is not the same as `array[1]`. In the first case, `numpy` will therefore interpret it as a zero dimensional boolean array, which, based on how masks works, is the same as selecting all data.

Therefore:

`x[True]`

will return the full array, just as

`x[False]`

will return an empty array.